# Selected using option ID

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="editSkillList">  
     <option id="0">Select</option>
     <option id="8">text1</option>
     <option id="5">text2</option>
     <option id="4">text3</option>     
</select><br><br>
```

Javascript code

```
document.getElementById("editSkillList").selectedIndex="2";
```

But i want set selected using option id.Is it posible? then please help me

Comment: Are you sure it's `id` not `value`?

Comment: @xdazz weird, though, value will be picked up anyways

Comment: Yes there is value also but i want to set using option id..Thanks for reply

Comment: If the options has values, you should add that, as that changes the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the selects value to the text you get from the option after targeting the ID

```
document.getElementById("editSkillList").value = document.getElementById('4').innerText;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5J6DU/)

**EDIT:**

If the options have a value, you just set the selects value to one of the options value

```
document.getElementById("editSkillList").value = document.getElementById('4').value;
```

Comment: document.getElementById(id).value;  this value got undefined

Comment: You have to run the javascript after the elements are added to the DOM, see this -> http://jsfiddle.net/5J6DU/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
document.getElementById('5').selected = true;
```

Replace `'5'` with the `id` of the option you need to select.

Comment: +1 - that's an even better solution, unless for some reason the select has multiple set

Comment: @adeneo - Yes, for multiple selects, this likely won't work. Haven't tested though.

Answer (score 0):

you can select your option using below code.

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("editSkillList").value = document.getElementById('4').value;
```

or you can use this code also.

```
var editSkillList = document.getElementById("editSkillList");

editSkillList.options[editSkillList.selectedIndex].value;
```

i hope it will help you.